# Apache2/WordPress giving SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH when viewed externally

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl

I'm hosting a site for a local company. Without SSL, the website loads fine, but when we try to access it securely, I get ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH (Except for when I try to view it locally)
When I go to check the logs, I don't see any issues. I've set the log level for this site to be debug, and I see a bunch of lines saying that authorization is granted, so I don't think the issue is with Apache2, but I don't know what the issue might be.
In the WordPress control panel, I've gone in and tried to make sure that all SSL controls there are disabled.

Here's my SSL config for the site:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
#SKIP log and serverAlias settings, as well as DocumentRoot. I can provide it it's really necessary
<Directory />
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
     Require all granted
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     Allow from all
     Order allow,deny
</Directory>
<Directory path/>
     Options FollowSymLinks
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
</Directory>
#SKIP SSLCert paths. CA is GoDaddy
```

When I use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest it comes back with an 'A' rating, so I'm confident that I've got everything set up, which makes me even more lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cybersec friend suggested the issue might be a keying issue with the certificate.
Needed to re-key the certificate, which resolved the error.